# How so i sum up the number of times the order state is each day?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this:

- id_order_state
- date_add

I want to trend how many times each day i get `id_order_state` **4** and **17**.

I tried like this but its not working the way i want:

```
SELECT `id_order_state` , `date_add` , COUNT( `id_order_state` )
FROM `ps_order_history`
WHERE `id_order_state` IN(4,17)
AND `date_add` LIKE '2017%'
GROUP BY `date_add`
ORDER BY `date_add` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now i get a result like this:

```
4   2017-10-12 11:51:56     1
4   2017-10-12 10:42:32     1
4   2017-10-12 10:41:29     1
4   2017-10-11 17:06:52     1
4   2017-10-11 17:06:47     1
4   2017-10-11 17:06:44     1
4   2017-10-11 17:06:40     1
4   2017-10-11 17:06:31     1
17  2017-10-11 17:06:28     1
17  2017-10-11 17:06:27     1
4   2017-10-11 17:06:26     2
17  2017-10-11 17:06:24     2
17  2017-10-11 17:06:23     1
4   2017-10-11 17:06:21     2
```

But i want it to be like:

For example: I have 5 id_order_state 4 and 3 id_order_state 17 on 2017-10-11

Result:

```
2017-10-11    8
```

Anyone that can help me?

Extra : limit the result to the last 30 days (per query)

Comment: Your sample data is for several days, but the expected result includes only one day. How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try date() function to convert "timestamp" to "date":

```
SELECT
    date(`date_add`) as date_add,
    COUNT(*)         as nb,
FROM
    `ps_order_history`
WHERE
    `id_order_state` IN(4,17)
AND YEAR(`date_add`) = '2017'
AND date(`date_add`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY
    date(`date_add`)
ORDER BY
    date(`date_add`) ASC
```

Result:

```
date_add      nb
2017-10-11    11
2017-10-12    2
```

Comment: Do you also have any idea on how to change the result to DESC but for the last 30 days instead?

Comment: Filter the last 30 days in your WHERE clause instead of using limit.

Comment: where condition : date(`date_add`) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

I've used a Common Table Expression (CTE) to combine grouping the dateparts by day, month and year but also to then present them as a coherent date (as in dd/mm/yyyy). You could work this along with Getdate() so that you could select only TODAY'S rows from any table that holds data from before today. I have put that at the end, you can just delete the /* and the */ if you prefer to use it that way. If you like, you can create a Stored Procedure out of it and just run the procedure (EXEC PROC sp_today), I've put that at the start.

```
--CREATE PROC sp_today
--AS

WITH CTE (a,b,c,d)
AS
(
SELECT 
COUNT(id_order_state),
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(DD,date_add)),
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(MM,date_add)),
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(YYYY,date_add))
FROM ps_order_history
WHERE id_order_state = 4 OR id_order_state = 17
GROUP BY DATEPART(DD,date_add),DATEPART(MM,date_add),DATEPART(YYYY,date_add)
)
SELECT b+'/'+c+'/'+d AS [date],a AS [nmbr] FROM CTE

/* WHERE b = DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) AND c = DATEPART(MM,GETDATE()) AND d =
   DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())*/
```